# How do I control logging in 3rd party libraries

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, slf4j

I have a Tomcat server running a Spring-based servlet.

I've set up `[project root]/src/log4j.properties` file as below:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d{HH:mm:ss} %m [%c{3}:%L]%n

log4j.logger.com.martincarney.bugTracker=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.martincarney.bugTracker.controller=ERROR
```

This correctly logs my own code just fine, but doesn't seem to have any effect on logging from within the various libraries I'm using. For example, I still get INFO logs from `org.apache.*` to the Eclipse console error stream during Tomcat startup, even if I add `log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN` to my log4j.properties.

I'm using `slf4j-api` and `slf4j-log4j` jars, obtained through Maven.

How can I take control of logging levels and targets outside my own code?

Answer (score 3):

Some libraries use other logging frameworks like `java.util.logging`.

You could redirect logging with [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/), see [SLF4J - Bridging legacy APIs](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html):

Redirection for Jakarta Commons Logging:

> To ease migration to SLF4J from JCL, SLF4J distributions include the jar file `jcl-over-slf4j.jar`. This jar file is intended as a drop-in replacement for JCL version 1.1.1. It implements the public API of JCL but using SLF4J underneath, hence the name "JCL over SLF4J."

Redirection for `java.util.Logging` ([SLF4J API](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html)):

> Installation via logging.properties configuration file:
>
> // register SLF4JBridgeHandler as handler for the j.u.l. root logger
>
> handlers = org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler

For configuration of `java.util.Logging` see [JUL API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html).

Some libraries like Apache CXF supports more than one logging framework, see [Apache CXF - Debugging and Logging](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html#DebuggingandLogging-UsingLog4jInsteadofjava.util.logging) .

Comment: matter of fact, I'm already using slf4j, didn't realize it wasn't the same as log4j.

Comment: Can you expand on using SLF4J to redirect logging? Just linking to other pages doesn't really constitute a proper StackOverflow answer.